# Can iOS Apps Still Target iOS 6?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Will Apple accept app updates targeting (with deployment target) iOS 6? I have an app I'd like to update but I don't want to bump the required version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple will accept this, but you have to make sure your app is working properly in all the OS versions (iOS 6 and above). Also you have to create ipa with Xcode 7.

Comment: I've investigated some more and it appears Apple requires apps to be built with arm64 architecture included. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117166/is-64-bit-a-requirement-for-publishing-to-the-ios-app-store. The iOS 6 SDK does not support this architecture, so is this answer still correct?

Comment: While building your app you have to follow all guidelines from apple. If you check in Xcode 7 still iOS 6.0 is available as a deployment target.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/41615